# Convert flask.Response to requests.Response

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, mocking, python-requests

I'm writing some tests and I'd like to convert flask.Response objects to corresponding requests.Response objects. So I have 2 Flask apps (e.g. `A` and `B`), and `A` makes internal calls to `B` (via `requests.post(url, json=payload)`). My goal is to properly mock those calls without even launching any servers, and the current solution looks like the following:

```
from unittest import mock

...

def mock_B_request(url, json):
    response = app_B.test_client().post(url, json=json)  # flask.Response
    # Some hacking should be done here, 
    # since flask.Respone doesn't have `.ok`, `.json()`, etc.,
    # so it will break the code inside app_A
    return response

...

# Inside the actual test method
with mock.patch('requests.post', side_effect=mock_B_request):
    response = app_A.test_client().post(url, json=payload)
    result = response.get_json()
...
```

Has someone already encountered with such a problem? What is the easiest solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I have found a very easy working solution:

```
def mock_B_request(url, **kwargs):
   response = app_B.test_client().post(url, json=kwargs['json'])

   # Hack a bit in order to make flask.Response
   # support the same API as requests.Response
   response_mock = mock.MagicMock()
   response.status_code = response.status_code
   response_mock.ok = response.status_code == 200
   response_mock.json = lambda: response.get_json()
   return response_mock
```

I hope it will be helpful for somebody.